# How to wrap double quotes around a variable

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, jq

So Idk I got the half right but other half I am missing so,

Input is

```
echo $p
jq 'if .tweet | contains('\"$p\') then . |= . + {'$p': 1} else . |= . + {'$p': 0} end' newfirst.json
```

The output I am getting is

```
if .tweet | contains("accelerite) then . |= . + {accelerite: 1} else . |= . + {accelerite: 0} end
```

The Output I want is

```
if .tweet | contains("accelerite") then . |= . + {"accelerite": 1} else . |= . + {"accelerite": 0} end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

> How to wrap double quotes around a variable [for use within jq script]

Write your own escaping function that follows the json specification and properly passes escaped string. Writing such function is nontrivial - study jq documentation and source code on how it interprets arguments and json documentation about what characters are allowed in fields and how to escape them.

---

Writing such a function would be cumbersome, instead pass the variable to jq and let jq figure it out. Research jq documentation and quoting in shell.

```
jq --arg p "$p" 'if .tweet | contains($p) then . |= . + {$p: 1} else . |= . + {$p: 0} end' newfirst.json
```

Answer (score -2):

Nevermind got it,

```
jq 'if .tweet | contains('\"$p\"') then . |= . + {'$p': 1} else . |= . + {'$p': 0} end' newfirst.json
```